# change image with jquery depending on alt tag

Tags: image, alt

I am using an RSS feed to display weather from an external source on my website. I would like to be able to change/swap out the images in the feed for my own images. The only thing that makes each image unique is its Alt tag.

```
<p>
<b>Tuesday:</b>
<br>
<img alt="Sunny" src="http://www.weather.com.au/images/icons/1.gif">
<br>
Sunny. Warm.
<br>
20 - 28
<br>
</p>
```

So, is there a way to recognize that the Alt tag is "Sunny", and replace this image with one of my own?

Comment: Which of the selectors have you tried?  Did you read the docs?  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be afraid to reference [the manual](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

```
$('img[alt="Sunny"]').attr('src', someUrl);
```

Comment: Problem now is that the original icons flash up briefly before my replacements load. I have tried preloading the images but that doesn't work. Any Ideas?